# i want to get data from database after filter between dates. I tried but no data found

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($data['start_date']) ||
            !empty($data['end_date'])){

            $sql = 'SELECT save_cards.*, 
                    save_card_transaction.first_doc_name,
                    save_card_transaction.second_doc_name,
                    save_card_transaction.txn_id
                    FROM save_cards 
                    RIGHT JOIN save_card_transaction 
                    ON save_cards.id = save_card_transaction.card_id
                    WHERE ';

            if(!empty($data['start_date'])){
                $sql .="save_cards.created_date <= DATE(" .$data['start_date'].") ";
            }
            if(!empty($data['end_date']) && !empty($data['end_date'])){
                $sql .=" && ";
            }
            if(!empty($data['end_date'])){
                $sql .="save_cards.created_date >= DATE(".$data['end_date'].") ";
            }

            $sql .= 'AND save_cards.is_verified =? && save_card_transaction.payment_status =? &&  save_card_transaction.first_doc_name IS NOT NULL && save_card_transaction.second_doc_name IS NOT NULL order by save_cards.created_date desc';
            $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($data['verify'], $data['status']));
return $result->result_array();
```

Comment: can you show me the sql at final?

Comment: Hello. What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on few info you gave mabe wrong if

```
if(!empty($data['end_date']) && !empty($data['end_date']))
```

to

```
if(!empty($data['end_date']) && !empty($data['start_date']))
```